# What's the correct way to add a UIImageView or UITextView to a custom UIButton class?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton, uitextview

I've built a custom UIButton class but I'm struggling to add objects without affecting the behaviour of the button.  I've shown the class below.  When I use the class in my main code and add a target, the button only works in areas not covered by the image or text.  How can I add objects and have the entire button area behave in the same way?

```
class TestButton: UIButton {
    var myText: UITextView!
    var myImageView: UIImageView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        let myImage = UIImage(named: "AnImage")
        myImageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)
        myImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: (myImage?.size.width)!, height: (myImage?.size.height)!)
        addSubview(myImageView)

        myText = UITextView()
        myText.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)!
        myText.isEditable = false
        addSubview(myText)

    }
}
```

Comment: You can disable the userinteraction for imageview and textview for getting the click on the button. Or can override hittest method.

Comment: You can simply put UIButton above all where ever you want and turnoff interactions of other components, instead of adding components into UIButton keep other components outside only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess here, hope it works.

`UIImageView` and `UITextView` does not normally allow "user interaction", meaning that the user can not tap them and expect the app to react based on that. That is probably why, when you tap on the Image view, that event is not passed through to the `UIButton` below.

Fortunately the fix is easy. You can set the boolean property `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true and you should be in business again.

So in your case:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let myImage = UIImage(named: "AnImage")
    myImageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)
    myImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: (myImage?.size.width)!, height: (myImage?.size.height)!)
    myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(myImageView)

    myText = UITextView()
    myText.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)!
    myText.isEditable = false
    myText.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(myText)
}
```

### Update (after your comment)

OK so I just tried to create a quick project with your button and...it seems to work, I can click on the imageView and I can click on the label and still get an answer from my function, so there must be some difference in how we've set this up.

Here is my `MyButton` button, awfully close to the one you've made, the only difference is that I've added a `backgroundColor` to `myImageView`, a `frame` on `myText` and `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` on `myText`

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    var myText: UITextView!
    var myImageView: UIImageView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        let myImage = UIImage(named: "AnImage")
        myImageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)
        myImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: (myImage?.size.width)!, height: (myImage?.size.height)!)
        myImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        addSubview(myImageView)

        myText = UITextView()
        myText.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)!
        myText.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 80, width: 100, height: 30)
        myText.isEditable = false
        myText.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        addSubview(myText)
     }
}
```

And here is my `ViewController` where I use the button

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = MyButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
        button.myText.text = "Hello"
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: MyButton) {
        print("It's alive!!")
    }
}
```

Which gives me this pretty UI

[image]

And when I tap either the red image, the blue button itself or the "Hello" label I can see this in my console:

```
It's alive!!
It's alive!!
It's alive!!
```

So the good news is that it seems to work, now we just need to figure out what the difference between your setup and my setup is :)

Hope that works and helps.

Comment: Thanks for coming back but, unfortunately, it doesn't work.  I've tried just placing the UIImageView and UITextView on top of the UIButton, outside the UIButton, but the two views obstruct the button.  Do you know how I can change the order of the objects?  I've tried "let myButton = UIButton()" "myButton.bringSubview(toFront: self.view!)"  The button target still isn't being called when the other two objects are in front of it.